# Edit Text does not stretch automatically when Landscape Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am really new in Android programming. I try to design chat layout but i found some problem of layout design. Why the Edit Text layout doesn't stretch automatically in landscape mode?

[Here is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eouxk.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/myappbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <include
            layout="@layout/input_message_area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/myappbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:background="#63DDEC"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_chat_story"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is for **input_message_area.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#63DDEC"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_a"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEmoji"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smile_center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEmoji"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_main"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/send_center"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/inputLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add weight to RelativeLayout.
please find my code. This will help you.

**input_message_area.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#63DDEC"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_a"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEmoji"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/smile_center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEmoji"
        android:hint="Type a message"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_center"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_main"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/send_center"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/inputLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really help.

Answer (score 1):

Give `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to your `Edit Text`.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEmoji"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change EditText width from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`.

**input_message_area.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#63DDEC"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_a"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEmoji"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smile_center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEmoji"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_main"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/send_center"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/inputLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

</LinearLayout>
```